# Akeneo - Import Product CSV - Import error - Field "sku" is expected, provided fields are

Tags: magento, akeneo, pim

I'm trying to create a csv product import example for Akeneo project.

I have created some products, with some data and exported them as a .csv file. Export is done correctly. I did some changes on product values(from downloaded .csv) like change of sku, product name and now i want to import them.

When i run the import of product there is displayed the following error:

```
FIELD "SKU" IS EXPECTED, PROVIDED FIELDS ARE "SKU   CATEGORIES  ENABLED FAMILY  GROUPS  DESCRIPTION NAME    PACK-GROUPS PACK-PRODUCTS   PACK-PRODUCT_MODELS PRICE-EUR   PRICE-USD   SUBSTITUTION-GROUPS SUBSTITUTION-PRODUCTS   SUBSTITUTION-PRODUCT_MODELS UPSELL-GROUPS   UPSELL-PRODUCTS UPSELL-PRODUCT_MODELS   X_SELL-GROUPS   X_SELL-PRODUCTS X_SELL-PRODUCT_MODELS"
```

Why it shows that error when in fact i am importing the csv format dhe was exported before?

---

[Edit]

The problem was that .csv generated was not saved on the right format(using ';' between fields).
After fixed it, import is still not working because of the following error:
[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiyHA.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your import file has no separator ";" between each field like that:
sku categories enabled family groups[...]

**When you save you csv file, take attention to select the separator ";" between data.**

The first line of your import will look like :

```
sku;categories;enabled;family;groups[...]
```

Comment: Yes you are right, the problem was the .csv structure without ';'. After fixed it, i have  a new error, do you have any idea why it is showed? Error is : {"TYPE":"CLUSTER_BLOCK_EXCEPTION","REASON":"BLOCKED BY: [FORBIDDEN\/12\/INDEX READ-ONLY \/ ALLOW DELETE (API)];"}.

Comment: It's an error due to storage and ElasticSearch. By default it's in "read_only_allow_delete" => true mode - that mean that if he don't have enought memory for an update, it switch to ready-only mode
-> you can found more information about this issue here : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/forbidden-12-index-read-only-allow-delete-api/110282/2